# SQL JOIN using Concatenated Field

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, concatenation

I have two tables, Table1 contains a column with what constitutes a partial value of a column in Table2, for example:

> Table1.XName = "123456"
>   Table2.ZName = "ABC-123456"

I need to create a JOIN that matches these up, but with MS-SQL 2008 I'm having trouble making this work.  Here's a sample of my attempt:

> SELECT * FROM Table1
>   LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON ('ABC-'+Table1.XName)=Table2.ZName

It doesn't matter what type of JOIN I use, or in which direction either, it fails.  I know I'm doing something boneheaded here so if anyone can point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Comment: What exactly does "it fails" mean? Do you get an error? Do you get wrong results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me:

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (XName VARCHAR(200))
DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (ZName VARCHAR(200))

INSERT
INTO    @Table1
VALUES  ('123456')

INSERT
INTO    @Table2
VALUES  ('ABC-123456')

SELECT  *
FROM    @Table1
LEFT JOIN
        @Table2
ON      ZName = 'ABC-' + XName

---

123456  ABC-123456
```

Could you please post the definitions of your tables and the error message you get?

Comment: Actually, I figured out that I was fat-fingering the full table name in the JOIN portion.  So the = 'ABC-'+Table1.XName was incorrect and should have been flipped as Table1.XName = 'ABC-'+Table2.ZName

Answer (score 4):

Random guess...

`Table1.XName` datatype is a number (not character based) so you get conversion errors

```
SELECT * FROM
Table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
Table2 ON 'ABC-' + CAST(Table1.XName as varchar(30)) = Table2.ZName
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  Table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON
    Table1.XName LIKE CONCAT("%", Table2.ZName, "%") OR
    Table2.XName LIKE CONCAT("%", Table1.ZName, "%")
```

Please mark the answer if that works for you.

Comment: this does not seem to work for me. "specified number was invalid" is always the result. CONCAT worked.

Comment: Thanks. Updated answer.