# Inner join on ConCat fields

Tags: sql

## I have table A

```
Code  Range
A     12569 
B     18175
C     478931
```

## And Table B

```
id      Type 
A12569  0
B18175  1
C478931 0
```

How can I concatenate the two fields of the first table, in order to join them with the second table.

I have tried with the following  query

```
SELECT concat(A.code,B.Range),b.Type FROM DB.tableA A
inner join DB.tableB B 
on Concat(A.code,B.Range)= B.id;
```

Comment: Depends on your DBMS and the datatypes.  Tag/add that information to your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL JOIN using Concatenated Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692821/sql-join-using-concatenated-field)

Answer (score 0):

Just concatenate the two columns:

```
select *
from table_a a 
  join table_b b on a.code||range = b.id;
```

The above is standard SQL - not all DBMS respect that though and use a different operator to concatenate strings.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server:

```
Select a.Code+b.Range as id, b.Type from TableA a inner join tableB b on a.Code + b.Range = b.id
```

Untested but should work - presumption is all columns are varchar or nvarchar.  May need to add some casting on the range field if that's not the case.